# Custom mod rewrite function not responding

Tags: url-rewriting

My url is

```
http://domain.com/author/john/?posts=pending
```

What I want is

```
http://oyecow.com/author/john/pending
```

My function

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(author)/([A-Za-z0-9_- ]+$*)/?', 'index.php?posts=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'create_custom_rewrite_rules');

add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'pending';
    return $vars;
}
```

In my author.php I've added

```
$check = get_query_var('pending');
if ($check = 'pending') { echo 'yay' ;}
```

The author name can have alphanumeric (both uppercase and lowercase) and dash. I flushed rules form wordpress permalinks, but still my seo url is showing 404 error page.

Comment: Firstly, your regex doesn't look right to me. Have you tested it? I don't see how that matches a forward slash.

Comment: Secondly, your query_vars filter callback should register the name of the variable, not its value: `$vars[] = 'posts';`. Also, I'd avoid using the variable name 'posts' completely.

Comment: I also think they problem is with this part `('^(author)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+$*)` and the `$vars[] = 'posts';` gives me error **Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 26 in in wp-class.php** I've replaced the **posts by view**, but no success

Comment: Sorry, the above warning was coming from regex. I'm trying

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple endpoint, use [`add_rewrite_enpoint`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) instead of adding a rule and query var.

```
function wpd_author_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'pending', EP_AUTHORS );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_author_endpoint' );
```